# Why "singular" in "singular homology/cohomology"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology

As the title suggests, I'm curious to know whether there is any reason why the word "singular" appears in "singular homology/cohomology".

Comment: The maps are merely continuous, rather than smooth (or some similar category).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because to obtain our chain complex for a space $X$ we look at arbitrary maps $\Delta^n \to X$ which are not necessarily nice, i.e. singular. In contrast we look at nice embeddings when dealing with simplicial homology.

Comment: That's also the explanation I was given in my topology course.

Comment: Does the map needs to be continuous?

Comment: Yes. But that is it. No further restrictions.